# Dynamic iframe loading and acccessing print method - same domain

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, web

I have an iframe element placed on page, when user clicks specific button - the iframe (which is placed in UpdatePanel) gets an SRC attribute filled in with my url, and update panel is refreshed.

This way I get the PDF file shown in iframe, however now I want to print it.
And I am getting

> Error: Permission denied to access property 'print'

```
$('#ifOrderPrint').get(0).contentWindow.print();
```

The PDF file is generated by ASPX page, which returns the PDF using

`Respone.WriteBnary`, and this URL is passed to the iframe as an SRC attribute.
`mypage.com/GetPdf.aspx?id=100`

Both main page and iframe src are in the same domain.

What I've found is that, when I load the `src` attibute - the link gets prefixed with `http://` and leads to the above error when called to.
If I edit the SRC tag in firebug, and remove the prefix, I'm getting an XML Parse error, but I am able to access the `print method (!)`

Is than an issue with IIS configuration that links without `http://` are not working?
How can I access the print method of my iframe? The cross domain security shouldn't apply here as its the same domain, any ideas?

Comment: Note: this occurs in Firefox, Chrome browser has no issues letting me access the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a function in iframe page which then call a window.print() function from its parent window on iframe page

in iframe:

```
function childPrint()
{
   window.print();
}
```

in call from parent as:

```
document.myFrameId.childPrint();
```

Comment: When the PDF is loaded into the iframe, theres no access to the JS that is on the `GetPdf.aspx` page

Comment: @Savio You have no js access because that page only shows none other than pdf file?

Comment: the page loads, creates the PDF file and then writes the pdf file to browser. This results in default pdf viewer displaying the pdf in the iframe.